# StratosLive and ESB not accessable via URL

Tags: wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

I'm currently building a showcase with WSO2 ESB on the Stratos Live environment.
I deployed a proxy service and API which should be accessable via the following URLs:

http://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com:8280/t/DOMAINNAME/imageservice
http://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com:8280/services/t/DOMAINNAME/TestProxy

But if I try to open those links nothing happens and after a couple of minutes I get an 504 error. Do I have to configure any additional parameters or security settings to access it?

Regards,
Manu

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How do I start diagnosing what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No You do not have to configure any additional parameters or security settings. You can just create proxy/api in the usual way. I have created my proxy/API and was able to access in the below manner. Can you try again, maybe it took some time to get deployed to worker nodes.

http://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com:8280/services/t/amani123.com/MyProxy?wsdl
http://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com:8280/t/amani123.com/api

Answer (score 0):

I tried it locally without stratoslive and it works like a charm.
localhost:8280/testapi

But on stratoslive the url doesn't respond (with /t/DOMAIN/).
I think something is wrong with the API url?!?

http://esb.stratoslive.wso2.com:8280/t/manuel-test.de/services/customereu

**Source Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry"/>
 <sequence name="CallCustomerServiceEU">
   <send>
     <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://DOMAIN.net/service/customers/testname/"/>
     </endpoint>
   </send>
 </sequence>
 <sequence name="fault">
   <log level="full"/>
 </sequence>
 <sequence name="main">
   <log/>
  <drop/>
 </sequence>
 <api name="APICustomerEU" context="/t/manuel-test.de/services/customereu">
   <resource methods="GET" inSequence="CallCustomerServiceEU">
     <outSequence>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
   </resource>
 </api>
</definitions>
```

Comment: I also noticed that "/t/" doesn't work in the api context locally as well. Is there still no one with the same problems? Tried also to set up a new account at wso2 but didn't work either :(